# Export symbol as "module.exports", but keep type declarations in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, commonjs, es6-modules

I'm developing a node.js plugin in TypeScript.

The requirements are to export it as `module.exports` directly, e.g. when compiled, the `index.js` should look like this:

```js
module.exports = require('./src/plugin.js').default;
```

My `plugin.ts` looks like this:

```typescript
import {Options} from './types';

export default function myPlugin(options?: Partial<Options>): any {
  // ...
}
```

I can achieve the desired result by writing my `index.ts` like this:

```typescript
import myPlugin from './src/plugin';

export = myPlugin;
```

However, if I do this, the `Options` type would not be exported in type definitions.

And, it's not possible to use `export = module` construct with another exports for types.

I want the consumer to be able to import both the plugin function and the types for it:

```typescript
import myPlugin = require('@acme/my-plugin');

import {Options} from '@acme/my-plugin';
```

Is it possible for the consumer to be able to import types from my module as well as it's main symbol?

Comment: What about `export {myPlugin as default, Options}`? Then your customer could do `import myPlugin from "@acme/my-plugin"` and `import {Options} from '@acme/my-plugin'`

Comment: @barbsan `export default symbol` is different from `export = symbol`. In the first case you will get `module.exports = { default: symbol }` as output.

Comment: I know it's different, that's why I wrote it as comment - it would allow your customers to import both plugin and options but with `require` they'll have to use `require("yourmodule").default`,

Comment: Thanks @barbsan, but as I said in the question: `The requirements are to export it as module.exports directly`. It's a rule of the plugins ecosystem.